# Why is the normal force of a traffic light pole merely exerted by the right bolt?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statics

In reference to a recent statics problem, please see inserted picture for the correct situation below, it was required to find the magnitude of force ($F_3$), exerted by the leftmost bolt on the entire traffic light setup, in order to maintain static equilibrium. Now what doesn't seem logical is the fact that $\vec F_n$ is solely exerted by the rightmost bolt and not by the entire pedestal of the traffic light. According to my understanding, the normal force is exerted by the whole bottom plate. Nonetheless, this is incorrect, but why? This problem is similar to a standing person where the person's center of mass is not perfectly in between the two legs, but more directed to the left leg for example. As a result, the person would experience a greater force exerted on his/her left leg, compared to the right leg, again, why is this?

Thanks in advance.

Jelle

[image]

Comment: If the bolts weren't in place, which way would the traffic light move?

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison with a person standing on two legs is the right idea, but you didn't take it far enough.

Suppose the person is standing on two legs with one arm stretched out and holding a heavy weight. If the weight is heavy enough, the person will fall over when one leg rises from the ground.

The difference between the person and the traffic light is that the bolts can apply an upwards force to the light as well as a downwards force. That would be the same as if the person's shoes were fixed to the ground with glue, magnets, or whatever.

Note, IMO I don't really like these type of problems because they *do* make incorrect assumptions about the real-world situation. In real life, the both bolts would be tightened to squeeze the base of the light against the ground, and your "common sense" idea that both bolts would have a force in the *same* direction would be correct. In the diagram, that would be equivalent to increasing the magnitude of $F_1$ so that it was the weight of the lamp *plus the tension in the bolts.*

The question ignores the extra tension in the bolts, which applies equal and opposite forces to the ground and the base of the lamp.

Comment: I am not a civil engineer so I do not know WHY this is done, but many new installations in my area (Pennsylvania USA) are resitng on nuts threaded on the anchor bolts. The base plate does not touch the ground. This arrangement is shown in the figure, so the free body diagram is reasonable. The bolts have no significant preload.

Comment: @JohnHoltz, I suspect that it is much easier to determine if there is corrosion on the bottom of the lamp post base if you can see it, and maintenance is much easier if you can get paint to the bottom of the base.